# select a count of all messages with de date of the latest

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hello I would like to show a list of all messages with the date of the latest message.
I've acomplished the list.

SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTimes, TrackRecord.message_identifier, MessagesInstalledApplications.messageKind
FROM TrackRecord INNER JOIN MessagesInstalledApplications ON TrackRecord.message_identifier = MessagesInstalledApplications.message_identifier
WHERE TrackRecord.track_record_id 
NOT IN (SELECT track_record_id FROM TrackRecordLogEntry) AND MessagesInstalledApplications.application_id = 1
GROUP BY TrackRecord.message_identifier, MessagesInstalledApplications.messageKind

This returns:

```
NumberOfTimes   message_identifier  messageKind
1093    4203344 error
176 11558913    error
563 11558912    warning
```

I would like to add the latest date to that. The date field is: TrackRecord.date_record

can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So add `max(TrackRecord.date_record)`?

Be careful with that `NOT IN`, btw. `TrackRecordLogEntry. track_record_id` should have a `NOT NULL`-constraint. Also, I don't think SQL Server's query planner will rewrite that to an anti-join, so you might want to do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks! that's it... The track_record_id has a NOT NULL constraint on it. what do you mean with a anti-join? I don't get that part.

Comment: It's covered in depth here: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/

Seems that the planner does handle the NOT IN-with-NOT NULL-constraint after all. :-)